# Label not picking up DropDownList value on page load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This code is in my page load:

```
        If DDLSelectedYear.Items.Count = 0 Then
            For Each item As ListItem In selectedYear.Items
                DDLSelectedYear.Items.Add(item)
            Next
        End If
        If DDLSelectedYearEnd.Items.Count = 0 Then
            For Each item As ListItem In selectedYear.Items
                DDLSelectedYearEnd.Items.Add(item)
            Next
        End If

valYear = DDLSelectedYear.SelectedValue
labelSearchDate.Text = valYear
```

DropDownList Values:

```
2013
2014
2015
```

Label Value (expected to automatically populate on initial page load):

```
2013
```

The selected value isn't getting picked up by the label on page load, any idea how to get this work?
Thanks

Comment: thanks for your reply but this code is all in the page load

Comment: I think my question may have been misleading, I have tried to change the question, the DDL is populating correctly, but the label isn't picking up any value (usually it picks up on the first value on the list on load but because this is being populated dynamically I guess it works differently?)

Comment: have added some detail to the question, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: can you add total code for your page_load event?

Answer (score 1):

Check in the `SelectedItemChanged` event for your drop down list and you will see the correct `SelectedValue` there.

Comment: thanks for your reply, the DDL is populating correctly, but the label isn't picking up any value on page load (usually it picks up the first value on the list on load but because this is being populated dynamically I guess it works differently?)

Comment: @neeko - yes, it works differently because in `Page_Load` the controls are being re-created dynamically, thus the `SelectedValue` is not set at that point, the `ViewState` married up to the IDs of the re-created controls makes that "magic" happen. When the drop down list is re-built with the `DDLSelectedYear.Items.Add(item)` line, it populates the drop down list and the first item in the list is the selected value. In the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, which fires after `Page_Load`, then you should see the correct `SelectedValue`, if not then you most likely have `ViewState` disabled.

Comment: sorry I'm confused, very new to this! I want the label to pick up the first item in the list on page load, in other words, when the page loads the label has the value of the first item on the list

Comment: @neeko - every page load you want the label to be updated with the text of the first item in the drop down list, not just the first page load?

Comment: the label text will be the first line item unless the user selects another value

Answer (score 0):

Add If Not Page.IsPostBack check in your page load method before filling DDL and add SelectedItemChanged event handler as proposed by @Karl Anderson